# Is there an "easy" way to migrate installed extensions from Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2019 when installed side-by-side?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've been working in Visual Studio 2017 and over time have installed and configured several extensions to improve my workflow.

I recently installed Visual Studio 2019 side-by-side and want to start migrating my solutions onto it so I can benefit from the new features, etc. however it doesn't appear to have migrated any of the extensions I have in VS2017. I could install them one by one but reconfiguring everything to exactly the way I had them before would be painstaking and I'd surely miss something.

I would think this would be a feature built into the VS installer, but apparently it isn't unless I missed it. Presumably any automated import function would check compatibility with the new version and warn the user for incompatibilities that might be found.

I've loaded one of my previous solutions in VS2019 and have looked through some of the menus and settings dialogs, but don't see any way to automatically import the extensions.

I've also searched online and in Microsoft's documentation but can't seem to find anything that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "*automatic import for extensions*". You could try to update your extensions manually.
This steps for VSIX extension files. Use it if you have vsix installer but it doesn't support VS2019.

1. Rename file extension from vsix to zip
2. Unzip
3. Open extension.vsixmanifest, manifest.json and catalog.json and for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor change version to [15.0,)
4. Open extension.vsixmanifest and also replace all [15.0,16.0) by
   [15.0,17.0).

   Add the prerequisite in this way:

```xml
<Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
```

5. Zip all files
6. Rename to vsix

Also you could try to move extensions manually. Use it if your extension in not in vsix.

1. Find **your** extensions in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\`
2. Copy them into `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\`
3. Make steps 3 and 4 from "VSIX update"

Comment: Shame on me for using such a subjective word like "easy" in my title, but I wouldn't call this solution easy (though it would almost guarantee all configurations/settings come over). I have 44 folders in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions` so to go into each one and make changes to 3 files in each seems like a lot of work. Additionally this doesn't do any compatibility checks on the packages which I'd expect an automated solution to perform (I know I don't state this in my question, I'll edit it).

Comment: @Luke also you don't need all this 44 extensions, because almost all of them are from Microsoft. You only nee 3-4 of them. Yes second way is not easy). First way is useful if you have vsix installer but it doesn't support VS2019. Second - if your extension in not in vsix.

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Make sure that you also update ALL NESTED EXTENSIONS. Sometimes there is another vsix within your extension. You need to repeat the process for those as well.

Comment: Some extensions seems to be located in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_<someDigits>\ (VS2017) and %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_<someDigits>\ (VS2019)

Answer (score 3):

The Extension Manager extension (different versions for [VS2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ExtensionManager) and [VS2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ExtensionManager2019)) allows you to export a list of extensions and then import it.

Useful also in cases when copying between machines or users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried this but it only addresses the installation of my previous extensions. Certainly a time-saver but it did not bring over the configurations from the VS2017 environment, which is the bigger inconvenience to me.